# FabricJS ClipTo with Image or SVG As Canvas Boundary

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How can I use clipTo with an image or SVG? I want to restrict any objects from going beyond the SVG shape outline / image outline.

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to [this OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744506/fabric-js-define-bounds-limits-for-images), however the responses did not seem clear to me how to accomplish this.

I can use clipTo with regular a shape, for example:

```
        var circle = new fabric.Circle({
            radius: 150,
            stroke: '#f55',
            fill: "transparent",
            top: 50,
            left: 50
        });
        circle.selectable = false;
        canvas.add(circle); 
        canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {
            circle.render(ctx);
        };
```

See this fiddle for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/o9f4dqjn/1/

However I can't get this to work with an image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this solution does not use clipTo, it works.

From: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2313

And my modified working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w396uhnv/

Basically you need to set the background image, and then set `yourobject.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';` on the object.

Note, the background image needs to have a transparent background, but non-transparent fill.

---

I could get clipTo method to work with SVG only (not an image):

```
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL('http://fabricjs.com/assets/23.svg', function (objects, options) {
            var shape = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options); 
            canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {
                shape.render(ctx);
            };
            canvas.renderAll();
        });
```

[Fabric.js Clip Canvas (or object group) To Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816753/fabric-js-clip-canvas-or-object-group-to-polygon)